# How to apply different styles in <li> in same <ul> parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have created a `<ul>` list with 3 `<li>` inside them. But I want each `<li>` to have different margin-top. But whenever I am applying margin to seperate `<li>` by giving different class names also, still all the `<li>` comes down by that margin and not that specific `<li>`. I changed the margin-left property of each `<li>` by selecting them with the class name and that works but margin-top is not working. Can someone please help me how to achieve it? Below is my code.

```css
 .person-rating li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(104, 69, 104);
    background-color: rgb(104, 69, 104);
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
```

```html
    <div class="person-rating">
      <ul>
        <li class="new-1">
          <img src="images/image-anne.jpg">
          <h4>Colton Smith <br>
            Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
          Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
          Excellent!"</p>
        </li>
        <li class="new-2">
          <img src="images/image-colton.jpg">
          <h4>Irene Roberts <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
          delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."</p>
        </li>
        <li class="new-3">
          <img src="images/image-irene.jpg">
          <h4>Anne Wallace <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
          standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the margin top? Show that code (and your css is invalid)

Comment: Probably it's a problem of specificity: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS

add vertical-align `vertical-align:top;` on `li`

```
.person-rating li.new-1{}
.person-rating li.new-2{margin-top:30px;}
.person-rating li.new-3{margin-top:60px;}
```

```css
.person-rating li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(104, 69, 104);
    background-color: rgb(104, 69, 104);
    padding: 30px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.person-rating li.new-1{}
.person-rating li.new-2{margin-top:30px;}
.person-rating li.new-3{margin-top:60px;}
```

```html
<div class="person-rating">
      <ul>
        <li class="new-1">
          <img src="images/image-anne.jpg">
          <h4>Colton Smith <br>
            Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
          Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
          Excellent!"</p>
        </li>
        <li class="new-2">
          <img src="images/image-colton.jpg">
          <h4>Irene Roberts <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
          delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."</p>
        </li>
        <li class="new-3">
          <img src="images/image-irene.jpg">
          <h4>Anne Wallace <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
          standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have alrady specifed  `.person-rating li {`. So now style specifiing the Cascading order.

example:

```
.person-rating li.new-1 { ... }

.person-rating li.new-2 { ... }

.person-rating li.new-3 { ... }
```

and ofcourse have the `vertical-align: top;` in your `.person-rating li { }`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42qouz67/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left;` on your `<li>`. Then you will be able to set the willing `margin-top`.

Warning : it will change the display of your `<li>` into `display: block;`. You can define it explicitly, or let browsers do it for you.

More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

You can use the different classnames, or you can use :nth-of-type selector in css, but the behavior you experience is because they will be rendered in a row and this row by default will align/expand, I believe based on the browsers render logics (such as setting margin top to the highest value aligned etc).

However, you could simply use positioning like this:

```css
.person-rating ul {
  display: flex;
}

.person-rating li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(104, 69, 104);
  background-color: rgb(104, 69, 104);
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.person-rating li + li {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.person-rating li:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.person-rating li:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.person-rating li:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="person-rating">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="images/image-anne.jpg">
          <h4>Colton Smith <br>
            Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
          Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
          Excellent!"</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/image-colton.jpg">
          <h4>Irene Roberts <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
          delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/image-irene.jpg">
          <h4>Anne Wallace <br>
          Verified Buyer<br></h4>
          <p>"Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
          standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```